# Azure login cli for github actions without subscription

Tags: azure, github-actions, azure-cli

I was reading this documentation https://github.com/azure/login#configure-a-service-principal-with-a-federated-credential-to-use-oidc-based-authentication

And I have found that we can use **azure login cli** with `allow-no-subscriptions` parameter.

So my question is that what is the purpose of this parameter? although we have already defined the **subscription id** in the repository's secret when we can run this command

```
az ad sp create-for-rbac --name "myApp" --role contributor \
                            --scopes /subscriptions/{subscription-id}/resourceGroups/{resource-group} \
                            --sdk-auth
```

Because it outputs, **subscription id, tenant id, secret id, client id**.

Surprisingly, if I create app registration through azure portal I get an error

```
Error: : No subscriptions found for ***.
Error: Az CLI Login failed. Please check the credentials and make sure az is installed on the runner. For more information refer https://aka.ms/create-secrets-for-GitHub-workflows
```

Although the subscription id well defined in the secrets.

And if I just use that parameter

```
allow-no-subscriptions=false
```

Then I have no issue and it works like charm.

Comment: Have you seen this one ?https://github.com/azure/login#support-for-using-allow-no-subscriptions-flag-with-az-login. Also bot sure to understand what is your question ?

Answer (score 0):

For creating `rbac` from your local machine you need to upgrade **az module** and need to login Azure CLi using  `az login`

`az upgrade` , `az login`

[image]

```
 az ad sp create-for-rbac --name "myApp" --role contributor \
                            --scopes /subscriptions/{subscription-id}/resourceGroups/{resource-group} \
                            --sdk-auth
```

[image]

*The service principle is mapped to contributor role and subscription scope. *

*Please find the below screenshot*

[image]

For reference, please check this [Az CLI Login failed. Please check the credentials and make sure az is installed on the runner](https://github.com/Azure/login/issues/205)